# difference between mousedown and window.mousedown

Tags: dom

What is the difference between them? Devdocs says that mousedown is part of the dom level 3 events (not entirely sure what this means either) but windows.mousedown is a separate page on devdocs. Are the two different somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`window` is an object. An object contains information (values).  The values in an object are formatted into `name:value` pairs, or often referred to as `key:value`, or `property:value`.  If you see curly braces in JavaScript code `{}`, that's an object.  If you log something to the web browsers window, `console.log("some text" + myVariable);` and see `[object Object]`, then myVariable is an object.  You can add a `property:value` pair to an object with: `objName.property = value`.  `window` is an object.  It's an object with values in it from your browsers window.  When a function is assigned to `window.somename`:

```
window.mousedown = function() {statements here;}
```

That is putting the function into the window object.  Objects can contain all sorts of stuff: other objects, arrays, values, and even functions.  I'm explaining some background info for the sake of a more complete understanding.

Here is some documentation from Mozilla on functions and function scope:

[Functions and Scope Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope)

There is also **ON** mousedown

```
window.onmousedown
```

Is an event handler for the onmousedown event.

[Window.onmousedown event handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onmousedown)

A function can be assigned to an event.

`window.onmousedown` will detect a mouse down event **anywhere** in the document.  If you want to detect a mouse down event specific to a certain element, you'd probably put it into a button, or a image, or a input tag.

```
<label onmousedown='fncSendMail()'>
```

Example:

```
<script>
  window.onmousedown = mousedown;

  function mousedown() {
    alert("mousedown event detected!");
  };
</script>

<p>click anywhere to fire the mousedown event</p>
```

In the above example, `onmousedown` and `mousedown` are two different things.  `onmousedown` is an event.  `mousedown` is the name of the function.

So, what's the difference between `mousedown` and `window.mousedown`?   `window.mousedown` is being added as a `property:value` pair to your browsers `window` object, `mousedown` isn't.

The DOM is the **Document Object Model**.  It allows manipulation of the `Document` (Your web page.)  The DOM is an API.  It's an interface, which means that it's in between your code and your HTML allowing a connection between the two.   [Document Object Model Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/)

[DOM mouseup W3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/NOTE-DOM-Level-3-Events-20031107/events.html#event-mouseup)

[DOM mouse events](http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/NOTE-DOM-Level-3-Events-20031107/events.html#Events-MouseEvent)

Comment: But, could not `mousedown` also *be* `window.mousedown`?

Comment: No context was given, so there could be all kinds of possibilities.  Are you saying that `window` can be implied?  Maybe it can, I'm not sure.